# Solving a system of equation modul0 5

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

Consider the system of linear equations $$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -3\\ 2 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}  $$

a) Solve the system in $\mathbb{F}_5$

I just want to make sure my solution is correct:

We have: $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -3\\ 2 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\\ \Rightarrow A^{-1}= \frac{1}{42}\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 3\\ -2 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\\ \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 3 & \frac{3}{2}\\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \mbox{ } [5]$$

Therefore: $\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & \frac{3}{2}\\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{21}{2}\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} [5]   $

Comment: set the matrix $A$ up so the entries are in mod 5.  Solve for $\mathbf{x}$ and put in mod 5.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst So before I find the inverse matrix of A, I need to find entries of A modulo 5 ? What I did is I looked for the value of the determinant modulo 5 and then multiplied the inverse of that value with $\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 3\\ -2 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: The  LinearAlgebra[Modular][LinearSolve]  command of Maple ( see http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra%2fModular%2fLinearSolve )solves  linear systems mod q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that modulo $5$ one has
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix} 6 & -3\\ 2 & 6 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The latter matrix has determinant $-3 \equiv 2$, whose inverse is $3$, so 
$$
A^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1\\ -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_{2} \end{bmatrix}
=
A^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1\\ -1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}.
\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
which is your result, as
$$
\frac{21}{2} \equiv 21 \cdot 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}.
$$

Comment: I like this method better. Thank you

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol, you're welcome!

Comment: How did you calculate the value of 2 modulo 5 ?

Comment: In $\mathbb F_5$, $2^2=4$, $2^3=3$, and $2^4=1$, so that $1/2=3$.

Answer (score 1):

This method is legitimate since, if a solution exists, the determinant is non-zero mod $5$, and thus is invertible mod $5$.

To continue, $21 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1} \equiv 3 \pmod 5$.

So the solution becomes $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just have an additional question: before look for $A^{-1}$ should I look for the values of the entries modulo 5 ?

Comment: Either way is fine; it'll give the same inverse (although, sometimes it might reduce the arithmetic to reduce modulo $5$ first).  Working in matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_5=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ means that reducing entries modulo $5$ result in *equal* matrices.  This abstract algebra approach can make things easier.